# Ubuntu 14.04 Bluetooth adapter not found

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have multi-booted Ubuntu 14.04 alongside the pre-installed Windows 8.1 on my uefi-enabled HP Envy 15 Notebook. My WLAN card is a combo card, Ralink3290.

The problem is that my wifi works just fine both in Ubuntu and Windows, but I cannot get the bluetooth to work in Ubuntu. I have no problem with the bluetooth in Windows whatsoever. But in Ubuntu, the Bluetooth option in System Settings always shows "Bluetoth Adapter Not Found". The option to enable it is also greyed out. Also, I cannot enable it manually through my keyboard button. Seems that something is wrong with the adapter drivers.

Being a newbie in linux environment, I am not sure where the problem lies. I have gone through other posts, but did not quite get the solution. I tried installing Blueman and all, but did not work for me. I also installed the driver from Mediatek, but during installing it, I got an Error 2 response, which I am not sure why.

Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Did you found a solution?. I have the same problem.

Comment: I too have a similar issue with HP Envy 15 notebook. Is this a bug?

Comment: Nope. No solution yet. Browsed through various articles so far, still nothing. [This post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) could be of help if you are having a RT3290 Wireless card. Didn't work for me though. Please let us know if it works for you @AFVG

Comment: Either that or Trusty experiences issues with detecting the Bluetooth adapter when dual-booted with Windows 8.1. Not sure which @Raqs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: Sadly, no.@Rags

Comment: You must install the driver : You can find the solution in the first answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Followed the instructions. Compiled successfully. But fails to connect to any device! Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `rfkill list`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be related to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396021/what-is-causing-my-intel-7260-bluetooth-device-to-disconnect-when-i-unblock-it-w)

Try disabling USB 3.0 at the BIOS, and then try again. In the BIOS, the option will probably say something about "xHCI", which is another way of calling USB 3.0.